# SQL Join tables on text name(and not by id)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I would like to ask you if it's possible to join to tables by name field that are not primary or foreign keys ? 
I have a concrete example:

[image: My easy model]

On this example, i have tickets which come from 2 different apps, and each app give me the ticket name + username in different formats(so it's impossible to make it the unique id in the user_role table).

My request for the moment looks like that:

```
SELECT ticket_created_app1.user_name, count(ticket_created_app1.id),u.main_name 
from user_roles u
LEFT JOIN u on u.name_2 like ticket_created_app1.user_name
group by ticket_created_app1.user_name,  u.main_name;
```

As you understand, I want for each user, the number of tickets created and show the main_name from user_roles.

However, all the column u.main_name is empty.

Comment: LIKE? Does ticket_created_app1.user_name really contain any wildcards? Try `u.name_2 like '%' || ticket_created_app1.user_name || '%'`.

Comment: another answer is the good one, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want for each user, the number of tickets created and show the main_name from user_roles.

You could left join two aggregate queries:

```
select 
    u.main_name, 
    coalesce(t1.cnt, 0) + coalesce(t2.cnt, 0) nb_tickets
from user_roles u
left join (
    select user_name, count(*) cnt
    from ticket_created_application1
    group by user_name
) t1 on t1.user_name = u.name2
left join (
    select user_name, count(*) cnt
    from ticket_created_application2
    group by user_name
) t1 on t1.user_name = u.name1
```

If you want the numbers in two different columns, then:

```
select 
    u.main_name, 
    coalesce(t1.cnt, 0) nb_tickets1,
    coalesce(t2.cnt, 0) nb_tickets2
from ...
```

Comment: oh It works almost well, however i would like if possible 3 columns, u.main_name, number_ticket_app1 and number_ticket_app2. Is it possible ? i did that but no good answer : select 
    u.main_name, 
    coalesce(t1.cnt, 0) nb_tickets_app1,  coalesce(t2.cnt, 0) nb_ticket_app2